# Drupal 7 - Can't get form values from form_alter in node_presave

Tags: drupal-7, hook-form-alter, hook-form

I have added some custom fields in `form_alter` and I am not able to get the values in `hook_node_presave`. Am i missing something or should i use other form hooks to get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_node_presave` should not be able to retrieve form elements added to node using `hook_form_alter`. Simply, because `hook_node_presave` acts only on fields attached to the node object itself, not to the form being submitted.

So, what you are experiencing is the normal behavior.